# PHP variable, and change javascript properties

Tags: javascript, php

I have got the most biggest problem, I have see.

piece of code (just and example, the main example use database querys):

```
<?php $var1="999"?>

<script>
     bigvar= <?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>;

    var lolo = {
        big: 2
    }
    lolo.big=bigvar;
    alert(lolo.big);
</script>
```

Problem:
It does not recognize the PHP variable (it doesn't change to 999 value), and passing php value to javascript variable, doesn't work.How can help me ?.It is a big issue.

Comment: What do you mean "does not recognize", PHP is executed before JS, so JS isn't at any time aware that it's PHP providing the value.

Comment: remove  s tag </scripts>

Comment: if i copy and paste your code i get 999... does it return 2 to you?

Answer (score 4):

you should add quotes while assigning value from php variable to javascript, like as follows

```
 <script>
     bigvar= "<?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>"

    var lolo = {
        big: 2
    }
    lolo.big=bigvar;
    alert(lolo.big);
</script>
```

and its `</script>`, not `</scripts>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var bigvar= "<?php echo($var1); ?>"

    var lolo = {
    "big": "2"
    }
    lolo.big=bigvar;
    alert(lolo.big);
</scripts>
```

The above example works fine for me..Try it

Comment: Thanks, yes it works, but the main problem (the most bizarre I have see), remains.It is with howler js. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add quotes around your php, so your JS know that this value is a string.

```
bigvar = "<?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have done it: var bigvar= "<?php echo($var1); ?>" (I just have forgotten, to put ; in my example.Thanks

Comment: unfortunately, the issue remains